# On the frequency of Prime Factor 2 with upper bound n

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if this is true:

> $ \sum_{l=2}^n \max(2^{x} | l) < n$
>   For $n > 4,x \in \mathbb N$

(I hope I got that right), the Sum denotes the frequency of Prime Factor 2 in l < n. 
Is it true, that the frequency of Prime Factor 2 in all integers starting from 2 to n, is always less than the value of n?

Thanks

Comment: compare $\log_2 n$ to $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  As $1$ has no factors of $2$ we can start your sum at $1$ with no change.  Now note that the number of even numbers up to $n$ is $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$, each contributing at least $1$ to your sum.  The numbers that are multiples of $4$, of which there are $\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor$ contribute another $1$, the $\lfloor \frac n8 \rfloor$ that are multiples of $8$ contribute another and so on.  The sum of all of these is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\log_2 n}\left  \lfloor \frac n{2^k} \right \rfloor \le \sum_{k=1}^{\log_2 n}\frac n{2^k}=n \sum_{k=1}^{\log_2 n}\frac 1{2^k}\lt n$$
where we know the last sum is equal to $1$ if we continue it to infinity and we have deleted the trailing terms.  This indicates that the closest we can get is when $n$ is a power of $2$, and in fact your sum will be $n-1$ in that case.